# Question on sufficiency condition for complex differentiability

Tags: complex-analysis

> Let $f : \Omega\subseteq\mathbb{C} \to \mathbb{C}$ and all the partial
> derivatives exists at every point of $\Omega$. Suppose also that
> $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x} = -i\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}$ on
> $\Omega$. Then show that $f$ is complex differentiable on $\Omega$

Suppose $f = u + iv$

Here,
$\frac{\partial f}{\partial x} = -i\frac{\partial f}{\partial y} \Rightarrow \frac{df}{d\bar{z}} = 0$, i.e, the Cauchy Riemann equations are satisfied.

But we can't just yet conclude that $f$ is complex differentiable since we also need the partial derivatives of $u$ and $v$ to be continuous. So is this question wrong or am I missing something?

Comment: $\frac{d}{d\bar{z}}$ is an elliptic differential operator, so any solution (even in a distributional sense) to $\frac{df}{d\bar{z}}=0$ on an open set (this is crucial of course) is smooth etc; note that weird counterexamples to C-R but not complex differentiable involve non-open sets (eg isolated points etc)

Comment: **Riemann** – not Reimann! [Georg Friedrich Bernhard Riemann](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernhard_Riemann)

Comment: @MartinR sorry, I corrected it

Comment: @Conrad I only know the definition of that operator, nothing more than that.

Comment: not sure exactly what are the hypothesis of the question - if you just assume $f_x, f_y$ exist at every point in $\Omega$, then I am not sure that any simpler proof than using the ellipticity of $\frac{d}{d\bar{z}}$ work (this uses some theorems in distribution theory about singular support); the result is definitely true (C-R on an open set implies holomorphic regardless of any continuity assumptions on the partial derivatives)

Comment: It is indeed correct. Try searching Looman-Menchoff Theorem. But it is highly non-trivial result and most elemetary texts do not include the proof. If my memory serves me, you can find a proof in Narsimhan’s Complex Analysis book.

Comment: @WhoKnowsWho thank you very much, I will look it up.